# Troubleshooting IIS with MSMQ performance issues - Long response times sometimes

Tags: iis, performance, msmq

I am currently experiencing troubles with performance over the last few weeks and I need some aid in how to troubleshoot the Microsoft Messaging Que server.

The IIS and MSMQ resides on the same serevr. There is several application servers which process and return messages to the MQ. The architecture is similar to this:
[image]

For some reason sometimes the messages take ~10+ seconds to return to the IIS server and we think it is related to the MQ.

The IIS/MQ server and application servers have no issues regarding network, memory or storage. Everyone seems to be processing fast and without any problems.

I am wondering how I can both sniff messages and debug the MQ by sending my own messages (based on the sniffed data) to try to reproduce the latency troubles. Also if anyone has any good pointers in how to troubleshoot this I'd gladly accept any tips.

Comment: Ever found a solution? I'm experiencing the same problems.

Comment: I believe I solved it by removing the mq round robin load balancing. The mq was distributed through multiple DC's and I hard-coded the server to always just use one DC. I basically just hard-coded the arp table with 1 Mac address for all the DC's